Visual Studio: Is there a way to disable IntelliSense autocomplete for the enter key?
Is there a way to disable IntelliSense autocomplete for the enter key in visual studio? It's driving me insane that every time I try to insert a newline, IntelliSense throws a bunch of garbage code on the line instead. I've used other IDEs where tab is the button for autocomplete, and that worked perfectly. Usually you only need an actual tab character at the start of a new line where there is nothing to autocomplete, so once you start typing it becomes the perfect key to accept an autocomplete suggestion. I don't want to disable IntelliSense completely, just the enter key for autocompletion.
I'm currently in tools -> options -> text editor -> C# -> IntelliSense and I don't see an option to disable the enter key for autocompletion. Could it be somewhere else?

If you want to disable IntelliSense autocomplete for the Enter key, you can use the option to change the IntelliSense completion mode:
Edit > IntelliSense > Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion or shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+Space.
Or you can set the IntelliSense completion mode to Tab-only:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced > Default IntelliSense completion mode: > select Tab-only in the dropdown
Besides, you can also set Enter key behavior to Always add new line on enter in Tools -> options -> text editor -> C# -> IntelliSense


Thank you! "Edit > IntelliSense > Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion" was exactly what I was looking for.
I saw the "Always add new line on enter" option in the IntelliSense options when I was trying to figure this out on my own, but I assumed it would still autocomplete after pressing enter, it would just add a new line after doing so.
